# cd to a child directory of a symlink fails

Tags: bash, rhel, make, cd-command

To build a kernel module, you have to do `make -C` where `-C` is cd functionality.
As my make failed a lot of times, I found this:

```
[root@ror6ax2 modules]# ls -l /lib/modules/`uname -r` | grep build
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     54 Dec 17  2013 build -> ../../../usr/src/kernels/2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      5 Dec 17  2013 source -> build
[root@ror6ax2 modules]# cd /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build
-bash: cd: /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64/build: No such file or directory
```

I can't `cd` to directory that is after a symlink. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Does the directory exist and can you `cd` to it directly?

Answer (score 1):

Your `ls` call shows that `/lib/modules/2.6.32-431.1.2.0.1.el6.x86_64/build` exists and is a symbolic link. Changing to it complains that the file doesn't exist. This implies that the symbolic link is dangling: its target doesn't exist. You don't seem to have the kernel sources installed, at least not the right version of the kernel sources, at least no in the expected place.